# Use a result set in several queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a small backup of a quite big base (so the developers can download ~1-2gb instead of 15gb).

In order to do that, I have copied the base and I run a few scripts that truncate some tables (logs etc), and I want to delete data except for some users (always the same users).

Right now I have this:

```
-- delete order details not in test accounts
DELETE FROM order_details WHERE Album_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Album_ID FROM albums WHERE User_ID IN (
        SELECT User_ID FROM users
            WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com'
            OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com'
            OR Email_ID LIKE '%@zzz.com'
    )
)
DELETE FROM orders WHERE User_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT User_ID FROM users
        WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@zzz.com'
)

-- delete albums not in test accounts
DELETE FROM albums WHERE User_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT User_ID FROM users
        WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@zzz.com'
)
-- snip a few more of the same
```

As you can see, I always use the same `SELECT User_ID FROM users WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com' OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com' OR...` sub-query in quite a few places.

How would you do that so you don't have to repeat yourselves ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting the values to a temp variable and use the same in all where conditions.

```
DECLARE @table as TABLE(User_ID  Nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @table (User_ID)
SELECT User_ID FROM users
        WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@zzz.com'
```

---

```
DELETE FROM order_details WHERE Album_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Album_ID FROM albums WHERE User_ID IN (
        SELECT User_ID FROM @table))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use temporary table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmpUserID') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#tmpUserID
SELECT User_ID 
INTO dbo.#tmpUserID
FROM users
WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com'
  OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com'
  OR Email_ID LIKE '%@zzz.com'

-- delete order details not in test accounts
DELETE FROM order_details 
WHERE Album_ID NOT IN (
                       SELECT Album_ID 
                       FROM albums 
                       WHERE User_ID IN (
                                         SELECT User_ID FROM #tmpUserID
                                         )
                       )      
DELETE FROM orders 
WHERE User_ID NOT IN (
                      SELECT User_ID FROM #tmpUserID
                      )

-- delete albums not in test accounts
DELETE FROM albums 
WHERE User_ID NOT IN (
                      SELECT User_ID FROM #tmpUserID
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result in a temporary table

```
   -- create temporary table to keep track of users
   CREATE TABLE #users
   (
      user_id BIGINT
   )
```

Load the temporary table

```
INSERT INTO #users (user_id)
SELECT User_ID FROM users
        WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@zzz.com'
```

Then you can use the temporary table in your other queries.

```
-- delete order details not in test accounts
DELETE FROM order_details WHERE Album_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Album_ID FROM albums WHERE User_ID IN (
        SELECT User_ID FROM #users
    )
)
DELETE FROM orders WHERE User_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT User_ID FROM #users
)

-- delete albums not in test accounts
DELETE FROM albums WHERE User_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT User_ID FROM #users
)
```

This technique allows you to follow the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY_principle), since you just have the query defined in one place. If you need to change the business logic, you only have to change that one query, not 3 queries as in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question. SQL does not offer good capabilities to compose SQL queries which is unfortunate.

The best I can think of is a view or a table-valued function. You can create it at the beginning of your script and delete it at the end.

It is a bit of an ugly hack bit it still seems better than building SQL strings dynamically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table variable or temp table and store the Select query data

```
 Declare @User table
 (User_Id int)

 Insert into @User
  SELECT User_ID FROM users
        WHERE Email_ID LIKE '%@xxx.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@yyy.com'
        OR Email_ID LIKE '%@zzz.com' 

DELETE FROM order_details WHERE Album_ID NOT IN (
SELECT Album_ID FROM albums WHERE User_ID IN (
   Select User_Id from @User)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have foreign keys set up on your tables, then you could set them up for cascade delete.  If done properly, you would simply need to delete from the users table, which would cascade through to all of your other tables.

There's a ton of documentation regarding cascade delete, so I won't repeat it here, but it's certainly worth looking in to.

Comment: I don't really think OP wants to delete from Users table in this case, but cascade delete could save a few deletes. In the above example - order_details could be deleted with the album.

Comment: Yeah... it's a legacy DB, and there are like 3 foreign keys for a few hundred tables. And obviously, adding FK would take forever to clean the DB. So, good idea, but impossible to execute :(